# Bending a mesh without deforming the mesh pattern

Tags: mesh, surface-deform, curve-modifier

Here's another fun one. I have this layered model, with 3 layers. The top layer is a quilt pattern, the other two layers below are simple cubes. I need to bend them to separate them in a fan type layout.

[image: layers flat]

i've tried a number of ways, but the curve modifier seems to work best, except for the quilt mesh, which bunches up and smashes the pattern in a weird way.

[image: layers curved]

i need to figure out a way to curve the quilted top layer without destroying the quilt pattern. Any ideas and help is greatly appreciated. I'm totally stuck on this part.

[image: quilt flat, other layers flat]

I'm attaching the blend file, the curve-modifiers can be turned on and off to apply the curve for each layer, if you want to see what is happening.

thanks in advance!

Thanks Moonboots, this is much better! There is still a weird issue with the mesh though. It's fine when it is flat and the quilted indentions are into the fabric, but when the curve is applied, the indentions reverse across the entire surface, not just the quilted areas.

[image: flat quilt]
[image: curved quilt]

blender file
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The underneath topology is bad, delete it, select each opposite edge and use *Face > Grid Fill* to get a grid like that:

[image]

Also give a better *Resolution* to your curve called *BezierCurve.001*. Here is what it gives at the end:

[image]

Comment: thanks moonboots! Almost solved. I added a few more pics with the indention issue, if you have any thought on this.

Comment: ahh, never mind. I changed the deform axis to X and it fixed it. Thanks for your help!